# Node JS- HTML Links

Tags: html, node.js

I am new to node js, trying to make my first static web-pages using the technology. I have simply linked the css,images to my html file using node-js.

Now, I am trying to add links to my file but its not working. Below is my code of html:

```
<html>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./css/style.css">
  <h1 class="had"><a href="/next">Hello I m here</a></h1>
  <img src="images/download.jpg" alt="img not found">
  <img src="images/flower.png" alt="img not found">
</html>
```

and Node-Js:

```
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');
var path = require('path');

http.createServer(function(req,res){
   if(req.url === "/index"){
      fs.readFile("./public/index.html","UTF-8",function(err,html){ 
          res.writeHead(200,{"Content-Type":"text/html"});
          res.end(html);
      });
   }
   else if(req.url.match("\.css$")){
      var csspath = path.join(__dirname,'public',req.url);
      var filestream = fs.createReadStream(csspath,"UTF-8");
      res.writeHead(200,{"Content-Type":"text/css"});
      filestream.pipe(res);
   }
   else if(req.url.match("\.jpg$")){
      var jpgpath = path.join(__dirname,'public',req.url);
      var filestream = fs.createReadStream(jpgpath);
      res.writeHead(200,{"Content-Type":"image"});
      filestream.pipe(res);
   }
   else if(req.url.match("\.png$")){
      var pngpath = path.join(__dirname,'public',req.url);
      var filestream = fs.createReadStream(pngpath);
      res.writeHead(200,{"Content-Type":"image"});
      filestream.pipe(res);
   }
   else{
      res.writeHead(404,{'Content-Type':'text/html'});
      res.end("File not found");
   }

   if(req.url === "/next"){
       fs.readFile("./public/next.html","UTF-8",function(err,html){ 
          res.writeHead(200,{"Content-Type":"text/html"});
          res.end(html);
       });
   }
}).listen(3010);
```

Please, help me with this issues.

Answer (score 0):

Could you please tell whether all links or not working or only some specific one?

In your , the path to file might not be resolved, if your html file next is in the same directory then do it this way

```
 <html>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./css/style.css">
    <h1 class="had"><a href="./next">Hello I m here</a></h1>
    <img src="images/download.jpg" alt="img not found">
    <img src="images/flower.png" alt="img not found">
 </html>
```

if it's in some other directory then give the absoulute path

Answer (score 0):

Actually, this works fine on my machine, XD.

I highly don't recommend sending the paths into the server via the client and then using those paths to search for the file. This is a huge security risk as any file can be accessed on your machine just by entering a valid file path. Instead, use fixed paths and have the server serve static files on those specific paths.

Create a separate route to handle static files separately, it makes your life a whole lot easier.

You can use fs.readFile instead of createReadStream for serving images because it's easier for error handling, just send them out as a binary stream by adding the "binary" parameter in the res.send() function.

Lastly, I recommend using `<base href= "http://localhost:3010"/>` on the HTML file this makes all paths on the page relative to the base URL, in this case: `http://localhost:3010`. This way you won't get confused with all the paths.

HTML

```
<html>
<head>
    <base href= "http://localhost:3010"/>
</head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/style.css">
  <h1 class="had"><a href="/next">Hello I m here</a></h1>
  <img src="/images/download.jpg" alt="img not found">
  <img src="/images/flower.png" alt="img not found">
</html>
```

NODE.JS

```
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');
var path = require('path');

http.createServer(function(req,res){
  if(req.url == "/index"){
      fs.readFile("./public/index.html","UTF-8",function(err,html){
      if(!err) {
        res.writeHead(200,{"Content-Type":"text/html"});
        res.end(html);
      }
    });
  }
  else if(req.url === "/css/style.css"){
    fs.readFile(path.join(__dirname, 'public/css/style.css'), function(err, data){
      if(!err){
        res.writeHead(200,{"Content-Type":"text/css"});
        res.end(data);
      }
    });
  }
  else if(req.url === "/images/download.jpg"){
    fs.readFile(path.join(__dirname, 'public/images/download.jpg'), function(err, data){
      if(!err){
        res.writeHead(200,{"Content-Type":"image"});
        res.end(data, 'binary');
      }
    });
  }
  else if(req.url === "/images/flower.png"){
    fs.readFile(path.join(__dirname, 'public/images/flower.png'), function(err, data){
      if(!err){
        res.writeHead(200,{"Content-Type":"image"});
        res.end(data, 'binary');
      }
    });
  }
  else{
    res.writeHead(404,{'Content-Type':'text/html'});
    res.end("File not found");
  }

  if(req.url === "/next"){
    fs.readFile("./public/next.html","UTF-8",function(err,html){ 
      res.writeHead(200,{"Content-Type":"text/html"});
      res.end(html);
    });
  }
}).listen(3010);
```